# TeXShop end of document failure

Tags: errors, texshop

New to TeXShop, using ver 3.58 on Mac Mavericks.
Frequently I run into a LaTeX problem, fix it, Typeset again, and hit a
Runaway argument?
...

(See image; unfortunately I cannot copy from TeXShop console at this point.)
[image: TeXShop console failure]

The only fix I find then is to quit TeXShop, remove the files its recently created, and restart. Is there another way around this?

This is tail of console from the same TeX after 'fixing':

```
Output written on application2.pdf (27 pages, 1974254 bytes).
SyncTeX written on application2.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on application2.log.
```

Also, I'm concerned that TeXShop's unusual file handling (external files process unsaved files) interacts badly with Google Drive, leading to truncated files.

Thanks
Arthur

Comment: Welcome! In some cases, only removing the generated files allows compilation to succeed. It depends on the nature of the error. I don't usually quit my editor, though. I just delete the files and compile again. I don't know what you mean about TeXShop having `external files process unsaved files`. I doubt that TeXShop is processing unsaved files. I don't know how this would even be possible, since TeXShop does not do the compiling at all. From habit, I always save before compiling. But I think TeXShop, if I remember correctly, saves the file automatically in any case.

Comment: (Your image is not available.) One possibility is that the first compilation left some auxiliary file *incomplete* because you stopped the first compilation by starting the second one. An incomplete auxiliary file may contain unpaired `{}` and cause `runaway argument`. On TeXShop's console there is a **Trash Aux Files** button that does the job for you. In my case the button fixes problems and I do not need to reopen TeXShop.

Comment: As for file handling. It is really strange. TeXShop saves TeX files before it calls the compiler, not in the current folder but somewhere else. So it is possible that you produced some PDF file and the computer crashed, and then you lost the TeX file because you did not save the file by hand. Auxiliary files are usually *up to date*, but if you stop the compiler by hitting `x` on TeX's error it is possible that the last bit of message is not written to auxiliary files and the log file.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments everyone. Yes, I find that sometimes simply deleting generated files fixes the problem. It is reassuring that the behavior I experience is typical. I will try **Trash Aux Files**. 

If truncated files recur I'll report in more detail.